# ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID when trying to get image from S3 with rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, heroku, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I'm getting the following error in the console when I try to get images from amazon S3, with my rails 5.2 app (with ActiveStorage) deployed on heroku:

GET https://www.myapp-production.herokuapp.com/rails/active_storage/representations/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibW[...]/image.jpeg net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

I'm using heroku pipeline with 2 apps : myapp-staging (free dynos, no sll), and myapp-production(professional dyno + automatic ssl).
I've got a custom domain with ssl pointing to production app.

I can get images when I use the custom domain.

The problem occurs only when I use both staging/production.herokuapp.com/ domains.

Can't figure out what the problem is.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your included code so that horizontal scrolling is not required to read it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you expand the error info on the page, you'll get a more complete explanation:

`This server couldn't prove that it's www.myapp-production.herokuapp.com; its security certificate is from *.herokuapp.com.`

In certificates, a `*` only matches a single DNS label (e.g. containing no dots). So if you visit your app using `myapp-production.herokuapp.com` it will work, but to support navigating to the site with the `www` on the front, you will need to get a different certificate that includes the SubjectAltName `*.myapp-production.herokuapp.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that was de problem. 
I was redirecting all request from non www to www subdomain to avoid duplicate content for SEO in my route file.
I turn it off for review and staging app and it's now working.

I don't really understand why the certificat was invalid only for images, though...